# Bash: getopts through case

Tags: bash, getopts

I'm trying to get a getopts option through a case.

The way my script is setup now, I have a start, stop, status, help options and I want to add some -x options to that to control some variables.

If I don't use the start/stop/status then the -x variables work, but not when I do use them.

Pertinent sections of the code are as follows.

```
  # Variable initialization
  DOMAIN="google.ca"
  LIMIT="25"
  TIMEBETWEEN="10"
  INTERATION="1"
  PINGS="25"

  options='d:l:t:p:h'
  while getopts $options opt; do
    case $opt in
      d) DOMAIN=$OPTARG ;;
      l) LIMIT=$OPTARG ;;
      t) TIMEBETWEEN=$OPTARG ;;
      p) PINGS=$OPTARG ;;
      \?) usage ;;
  esac
  done
  shift "$((OPTIND-1))" # Shift off the options and optional --.
```

and

```
case "$cmd" in
 start)
  pingtest_start &
  sleep 2
  pingtest status
  exit 0;
 ;;

 stop)
  pingtest_stop
  exit 0;
 ;;

 status)
  pingtest_status
  exit 0;
 ;;

 help)
  usage
  exit 0;
 ;;

 *)
  if [ "$cmd" ]; then
   clear
   echo "Unknown command '$cmd'"
  fi
  usage
 ;;
esac
```

Other variables work, and if I use the start, then the defaults work.

Edit below:

I found a work around by putting the case for $cmd into a new option and changing the case to $OPTARG

New layout is

```
options='a:d:l:t:p:h'
while getopts $options opt; do
  case $opt in
    a) case $OPTARG in 
    start)
      pingtest_start &
      sleep 2
      pingtest status
      exit 0;
      ;;

      stop)
       pingtest_stop
       exit 0;
     ;;

     status)
      pingtest_status
      exit 0;
     ;;
   esac
   ;;
    d) DOMAIN=$OPTARG ;;
    l) LIMIT=$OPTARG ;;
    t) TIMEBETWEEN=$OPTARG ;;
    p) PINGS=$OPTARG ;;
    \?) usage ;;
  esac
done
shift "$((OPTIND-1))" # Shift off the options and optional --.
```

Comment: How do you define `cmd`? How do you get from the first code excerpt to the second one?

Comment: Updated the question with workaround. It works, but is likely not the best solution.

Comment: Do you invoke your script like `./script start -d a -l 42`? getopts is expecting the arguments to come first.

Comment: Are you defining cmd like `$cmd=$1` or like `cmd=$1`

Comment: @confused: you set variables like this: `cmd=$1` (note absence of `$`). Perhaps that was a typo. It is always best to include real runnable code in your questions.

Comment: @ConfusedHelpdesker See glenn jackman's comment. `getopts` stops as soon as it sees the first non-option argument, so you would need to `shift` the first argument before you start your `getopts` loop.

Comment: Yes, the $cmd=$1 is a typo. It was cmd=$1. I will try it with the arg at the end once I have some time to redo it. Right now it's working. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 1):

Do you invoke your script like `./script start -d a -l 42`? getopts is expecting the arguments to come first.
                    – glenn jackman

See glenn jackman's comment. `getopts` stops as soon as it sees the first non-option argument, so you would need to `shift` the first argument before you start your `getopts` loop.
                    – chepner